# Running time of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have this algorithm and I can't figure out what is its time complexity.

```
int oc(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int s = p[n][0];
    for (int i = n-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int a = p[n][i] + oc(i);
        if (s > a)
        {
            s = a;

        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

I assume there is (n-1) iterations on the for-loop but can figure out what is total running time when using the recursion.

Comment: (This is a _procedure_. To be an _algorithm_, there'd have to be a problem the procedure solves.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `T(n)` is a complexity of computing `oc(n)`. Since for computing `oc(n)` you are running for loop from `n-1` to `1` and recursively calling `oc(i)`, hence

`T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+...+T(1) (*).`

If instead of T(n-1) we put

`T(n-1)=T(n-2)+T(n-3)+...+T(1)`

in `(*)` equality we will get:

`T(n)=2*(T(n-2)+...+T(1))`

If we continue same iteration for `T(n-2)`, `T(n-3)` etc. we will conclude tô following equality:

```
T(n)=2*(T(n-2)+...+T(1))
=4*(T(n-3)+...+T(1))
=2^i*(T(n-i-1)+...+T(1))
=2^n*T(1)/2=O(2^n).
```

The reason of this complexity is - your algorithm calculating same thing for many times. 
If you memorize values in array for which you have calculated the value of oc function and add a check in the first part of function which will return the value directly from array (in case it is already calculated) instead of running loop and again doing same job, the complexity of you algorithm will dramatically change and will be `O(n)`, since the algorithm will calculate all values and store when doing first iteration of your loops.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! What would be a suitable algorithm to reach at most the O(n) time complexity using memoization ?

Comment: @PierrePasquet the memorization technique is very easy to use and your algorithm is very suitable, you just need to introduce 2 more arrays out of oc function and pass them as a params to oc: memo_oc int[] and flag_oc bool[]. Init flag_oc with false values i.e. We don't have any memorized/calculated value of oc for reusing. Set flag_oc[0]=true and memo_oc[0]=0. Replace if(n==0){...} condition with if(flag_oc[n]){return memo_oc[n];} and insert  "flag_oc[n]=true; memo_oc[n]=s;" line of code before "return s;"

Answer (score 0):

It is *O(2<sup>n</sup>)*. See how the number of iterations builds up for increasing *n*:

```
 n | f(n) = total iterations
---+-------------------------------------------------
 1 | 0
 2 | 1 + f(1) = 1 + 0 = 1
 3 | 2 + f(2) + f(1) = 1 + 2f(2) = 1 + 2.1 = 3
 4 | 3 + f(3) + f(2) + f(1) = 1 + 2f(3) = 1 + 2.3 = 7
...| ...
 n |  .... 1 + 2.f(n-1) = 2^(n-1) - 1
```